# Allow multiple up-votes for tag "experts"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, voting

Not sure if this idea has ever been floated before (couldn't find any reference with a quick search so I thought I'd throw it out there).

**Basic idea**

*If a user is considered to be an expert for a particular tag, allow them to up vote more than once on questions and answers with that tag.*

Recognition of expertise would likely be a topic for discussion but could be something like: rep associated with a tag is 10x or 100x the average user with any rep on that tag. It would not be unlimited up-voting; perhaps some logarithmically decaying number of additional votes based on tag rep, or maybe as simple as 1 extra vote.

**Rationale**

Though this may violate the egalitarian nature of the reputation/voting system it would allow experts on a topic to recognize exceptionally good answers in their area of expertise and perhaps encourage desired behavior from newer/lower rep users.

A lot of the discussion here on meta seems to focus on how we discourage undesired behavior and there are multiple mechanisms to prevent it (down voting, review queues, close voting, moderation, user banning) but there seems to be only one mechanism, highly constrained, that can be used to *encourage* desired behavior.

Answer (score 7):

> Though this may violate the egalitarian nature of the
>   reputation/voting system it would allow experts on a topic to
>   recognize exceptionally good answers in their area of expertise and
>   perhaps encourage desired behavior from newer/lower rep users.

<strike>Experts</strike> Anyone can do this using the [bounty system](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), which is designed to:

> A bounty is a special reputation award **given to answers**. It is funded
>   by the personal reputation of the user who offers it, and is
>   non-refundable. If you see a question that has not gotten a
>   satisfactory answer, a bounty may help attract more attention and more
>   answers. Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned
>   reputation, and attach it to any question as a bounty. *You do not need
>   to be the asker of the question to offer a bounty on it.*

In addition to that the super-close-voting privileges help more because they serve to fix a real issue, which is poor questions are increasing the signal:noise ratio on this site.

I believe the current voting system is fine in that it rewards well and "double voting" won't help here. Bounties will, though - and they already exist.

Comment: Good point - wasn't thinking about the bounty system

Comment: And much probably a "tag expert" has plenty of points to distribute.